# How Can I Fix Inconsistent Text Downscaling with a Rich Text Label In Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a rich text label that works fine under a resolution of 1920x1080. However, when scaled down to the resolution on my laptop, which has a 1366x768 resolution, the text on said label becomes janky and malformed.

[image: A picture of a rich text label with some lines like line 3 and 6 being partially cut off and line 13 being smaller than the others]

Some lines are cut off at the top or the bottom, and others are squished (as you can see in the image at lines 3, 6, and 13).

I'm using Godot v3.5.1 and the text font is Noto Sans Regular from [here](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans)

I tried enabling mipmaps, using the filter, disabling anti aliasing, disabling font oversampling and enabling GPU pixel snap under Project Settings > Rendering > 2D > Snapping. And out of all of those, only the pixel snap setting worked. Completely fixes the issue and the text is rendered properly.

However, this completely breaks an animation of a spinning circle that plays at basically all times during the actual gameplay. It becomes stuttered and shakes instead of the normally smooth animation it has otherwise. I realize this may possibly be fixed by using SVG instead of PNG sprites, but I feel like that's not an ideal solution in case other sprites get added. Especially since my game will also allow community members to add their own sprites for their own game play.

So is there any way to fix the text without breaking the animations, or make it so that the animations don't break with pixel snap enabled?

Comment: Hi, this documentation on [multiple resolutions](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/rendering/multiple_resolutions.html) may help. For apps and games made with godot I will set window size to the largest resolution (my monitor's resolution) I want to target. For apps, I'll keep stretch disabled. For non-pixel art 2d games, I'll use 2d stretch with expand aspect.

Comment: It doesn't really help, but I appreciate it. The docs were the first place I looked. Expand leaves a giant gray bar to the right of the game and keep at least centers it but the issue with the giant bars on either side also is not ideal. Right now I have it set to 2D ignore, which you think would work fine because the Godot Editor doesn't have any font problems at that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Project settings/display/window/stretch/mode = viewport worked for me.
Changed it from "2D" to "viewport".

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!